# Why copy constructor does not need to consider half-assignment in C++

Tags: c++, oop

I've read about that to avoid copy assignment operator from doing half-assignment (it throws some exceptions when copying items so the target of assignment come to a state of mixed old and new value). The code below provides a solution

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& m)
{
    Matrix tmp{m};
    swap(tmp, *this);  // only be called when copy succeeds
    return *this;
}
```

But it call the customized copy constructor first. Why the copy constructor doesn't need to check half-assignment as copy assignment operator does?

Comment: What do you mean by half-assignment? Perhaps self-assignment?

Comment: @n.m.: I believe OP is sufficiently explaining what they mean by "half-assignment" in the parentheses that follow the use of that term.

Comment: *it throws some exceptions when copying items so the target of assignment* -- If the copy constructor throws, then that's the whole point of the assignment operator being coded the way it is coded.  A `throw` by the copy constructor will mean the assignment operator just returns without any assignment being done to mess up the original object.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks, but I am wondering why we don't need to consider the half-assignment situation when we just simply use copy constructor? Like ```Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m){Matrix tmp{m}; swap(tmp, *this); return *this}```

Comment: @rd142857 A copy constructor is making a new copy -- it is not trying to adjust an existing object.  So the code you are showing in the comment makes no sense, since 1) a copy constructor doesn't return anything, and 2) You are creating a copy from a copy, which creates a copy, which creates a copy, which creates a copy, etc. etc.

Comment: @rd142857 you'll end with infinite recursion this. The copy assignment code simply delegates the copying to constructor. It has to be implemented somewhere.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you are right, I just can't read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because C++ will handle this, for you.

If an exception gets thrown in the member initialization section, by one of the members' constructors: any members already constructed will get destroyed as part of throwing the exception (in reverse order of construction). If an exception gets thrown in the constructor itself, all class members get destroyed automatically (in reverse order of construction), as part of throwing the exception.

If an exception gets thrown in a middle of copy-assignment, there is no magic rabbit to pull out of the hat, to be found anywhere, to restore all class members to their prior state before the copy assignment began.

Answer (score 5):

When running a constructor, there's no "previous value" to be corrupted by an exception that is thrown in the middle of the constructor.

That's essentially the point of using this construct+swap for the assignment operator.  Any exception will occur in the ctor *before* the swap even starts, so will not corrupt the previous value of the object being assigned to.